# Expected in: flat namespace error when importing

Tags: python, cython

When importing a module I created using Cython I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(./something.so, 2): Symbol not found: _something
  Referenced from: ./something.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in ./something.so
```

My C code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_something(void)
{
    printf("Hello iris\n");
}

int return_something(int x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

And my .pyx file is:

```
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef extern from "my_header.h": 
    void something()
    ctypedef unsigned int x
    int return_something(int x)

def my_func():
    something()

def x2(x):
    cdef int X = x 
    return return_something(X)
```

The `cimport`'s, `ctypedef unsigned int x` and `cdef int X = x` are my attempts at getting this to work and I'm not sure if they are needed. I have tried without these additions to no avail.

Finally, my setup.py looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import os
import numpy

# important to include "my_function.c" in the sources list
ext_modules=[Extension("something", 
                        sources=["something.pyx", "my_function.c" ],
                        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])]


setup(name="something",
      ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules))
```

I can compile the C code and run it so I'm guessing there is something wrong with the .pyx.

Comment: `something` isn't in your c file!?

Comment: I thought I was missing "something"! Thanks @DavidW, this solved it.

Comment: Glad that sorted it. (FYI - I've voted to close as a typo since I think that's basically what it was)

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition: the comments above helped me to figure out my actual error which I struggled with for a couple of days. In OP's case the term that he was importing in Python from C (C++) was undefined in his C / C++ program. In my case, I had some incorrect type definition, imagine for example

```
std::vector<int> generate_2CNF(
    std::vector<uint64_t> &
);
```

in my `.h` file and

```
std::vector<int> generate_2CNF(
    std::vector<long> &
){ ... }
```

in my `.cpp` implementation file. Strangely, for me it seemed that I compiled just the `cpp` part without `Python`, but didn't obtain any error.

With this inconsistency in my code, I got the same kind of error as the OP. Until the last moment, I believed that it is not a bug in the code, but rather a bug in the linker. It turned out that such kind of errors are not easy to catch, as the compiler doesn't help you to point out where exactly do you have inconsistency. If you use `Cython`, just double and triple check that there are no actual errors in your `.cpp` / `.c` code, as later it will be very difficult to debug it.